# How do I prevent re rendering due to helper functions from a context provider in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have been trying to optimise the my react code, my goal is to make sure existing toast components don't re render when new ones are added. or when I delete one toast, rest of them don't re render. all toasts live in toast provider.

current behaviour:

whenever I add a new toast, existing ones get re rendered.

whenever I remove a toast, the remaining ones get re rendered again.

Let me show some code first (only relevant part):

***ToastProvider.jsx***

```js
function ToastProvider({ children }) {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([])
  const memoisedClearToast = React.useCallback(() => setToasts([]), [])
  useKeyDown("Escape", memoisedClearToast)

  const addToast = (toast) => {
    setToasts([...toasts, toast]);
  };

  const dismissToast = (toastId) => {
    const nextToasts = [...toasts]
    const filtered = nextToasts.filter((toast) => toast.id !== toastId)
    setToasts(filtered)
  }

  const value = React.useCallback({ toasts, addToast, dismissToast }, [toasts])

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

***ToastShelf.jsx:***

```js
function ToastShelf() {
  const {toasts} = useContext(ToastContext)
  console.log(`toast shelf render`)
  return (
    <ol>
      {toasts.map((toast) => {
        return (
          <li key={toast.id}>
            <Toast
              id={toast.id}
              variant={toast.variant}
              message={toast.message}
            />
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ol>
  );
}
export default React.memo(ToastShelf);
```

***Toast.jsx***

```js
function Toast({ id, variant, message }) {
  const { dismissToast } = useContext(ToastContext)
  console.log(`toast render`)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dismissToast(id)}>
        <X size={24} />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default React.memo(Toast);
```

All Toasts are getting re rendered whenever I add a toast, looking at the code, only prop that's changing is coming via context and it's dismissToast function. How can I make sure, that whenever new Toast is added to the toasts array in context, components depending only on the dismissToast function don't get a fresh copy of dismissFunction ? The existing toasts don't need to re render whenever new one is added right?

I haven't been able to find a way around this. I have tried memoizing the `value` prop that is given to the context provider.

Comment: okay so dismissToast depends on toasts, because it reads the value from toasts to remove toast with given ID. i don't know how to proceed, I have tried splitting context into value and helper functions but that just made me realise helper functions need to be updated with every value change.

Comment: One thing that isn't right is your `const value = React.useCallback(...)` call. The `useCallback()` hook should accept a function as its first argument, not an object as it is in your example. Instead, you should be using `const value = React.useMemo(() => ({ toasts, addToast, dismissToast }), [toasts, addToast, dismissToast]);` and then wrapping `addToast` and `dismissToast`in the `useCallback()` hook (as shown [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#optimizing-re-renders-when-passing-objects-and-functions))

Answer (score 0):

You need to memoize all functions pass from the context. To memoize them wrap them with `useCallback`, and use an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-parameters) to set the state. Updater function pass the previous state instead of depending on it externally.

```
function ToastProvider({ children }) {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([])
  
  const clearToast = useCallback(() => setToasts([]), [])
  
  const addToast = useCallback((toast) => {
    setToasts(t => [...t, toast]) // use updater function to avoid depending on toasts
  }, [])

  const dismissToast = useCallback(toastId => {
    setToasts(t => t.filter((toast) => toast.id !== toastId)) // use updater function to avoid depending on toasts
  }, [])
  
  useKeyDown("Escape", memoisedClearToast)

  // no need to memoize the value, because toasts always changes
  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={{ toasts, addToast, dismissToast }}>
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

ToastShelf.jsx:

```
function ToastShelf() {
  // exract dismissToast here, and pass to rendered Toast components
  const { toasts, dismissToast } = useContext(ToastContext)
  
  console.log(`toast shelf render`)
  
  return (
    <ol>
      {toasts.map(toast => {
        return (
          <li key={toast.id}>
            <Toast
              {...toast}
              dismissToast={dismissToast}
            />
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ol>
  );
}

export default React.memo(ToastShelf);
```

Toast.jsx

```
// get dismissToast from props and not from context
function Toast({ id, variant, message, dismissToast }) {
  console.log(`toast render: ${id}`)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dismissToast(id)}>
        <X size={24} />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default React.memo(Toast);
```

### Working example:

```js
const { createContext, useContext, memo, useState, useCallback } = React

const ToastContext = createContext({})

function ToastProvider({ children }) {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([])
  
  const clearToast = useCallback(() => setToasts([]), [])
  
  const addToast = useCallback((toast) => {
    setToasts(t => [...t, toast]) // use updater function to avoid depending on toasts
  }, [])

  const dismissToast = useCallback(toastId => {
    setToasts(t => t.filter((toast) => toast.id !== toastId)) // use updater function to avoid depending on toasts
  }, [])
  
  // useKeyDown("Escape", memoisedClearToast)

  // no need to memoize the value, because toasts always changes
  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={{ toasts, addToast, dismissToast }}>
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  )
}

function ToastShelf() {
  // exract dismissToast here, and pass to rendered Toast components
  const { toasts, dismissToast } = useContext(ToastContext)
  
  console.log(`toast shelf render`)
  
  return (
    <ol>
      {toasts.map(toast => {
        return (
          <li key={toast.id}>
            <Toast
              {...toast}
              dismissToast={dismissToast}
            />
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ol>
  );
}

// get dismissToast from props and not from context
const Toast = memo(function Toast({ id, variant, message, dismissToast }) {
  console.log(`toast render: ${id}`)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dismissToast(id)}>
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  )
})

function Demo() {
  const { addToast } = useContext(ToastContext)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addToast({ id: self.crypto.randomUUID() })}>Add Toast</button>
      <ToastShelf />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(
    <ToastProvider>
      <Demo />
    </ToastProvider>
  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 100% !important; 
  top: 0;
  left: auto !important;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```